# Strange button style behaviour, changing colors like storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, button, triggers, styles

I want to style a button depending on a ViewModel property, which is not part of the button.

So I created the following

The Button XAML:

```
<Button Content="DisableButton" 
            Height="27" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="95,197,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="120" 
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonOffline}"
            Click="ButtonDisableClick">
    </Button>
```

The style (the Trigger with Property does not work. also tried DataTrigger)

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonOffline" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF808080"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF990000"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

The property

```
private bool isOnline;
        public bool IsOnline
        {
            get
            {
                return isOnline;
            }
            set
            {
                isOnline = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsOnline");
            }
        }
```

And my click handler

```
private void ButtonDisableClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var isOnline = (this.DataContext as ComboBoxSampleViewModel).IsOnline;
            (this.DataContext as ComboBoxSampleViewModel).IsOnline = !isOnline;
        }
```

Now if I click the button, something like a storyboard begins
and the buttons starts to change colors like an animation.

Whats wrong with the code?

**Update**
Reproduced in a small sample which just has the button features posted here.
Nothing (except the basic INotifyPropertyChanged implementation) else
which is not posted here.

Comment: I copy pasted the above example and it works fine?

Comment: Here the button changes slowly the color, switches back and changes color again. Target-color as given in the style, animation length for fade-in and fade out about one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set `Focusable` property to false, this will stop the button flashing.

```
<Button Content="DisableButton" 
        Focusable="False"
        Height="27"             
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="95,197,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="120" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ButtonOffline}"
        Click="ButtonDisableClick">
    </Button>
```

This happens because there must be some triggers in the default template that are changing the background property.

The second solution is create your own template to button.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonOffline" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Border CornerRadius="2" x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF808080"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF990000"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>              
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you! Can you elaborate why this is happening?

Comment: @MareInfinitus check my answer again!